# Insert And Create Table If Not Exists ... On Duplicate Key Update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

As the title states, is it possible to add  a `create table` query with an `insert` query.

My insert query is like:

`INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (:column1, :column2) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column2 = values(column2)`

And I want it to be like

`INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (:column1, :column2) AND CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tablename (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column2 = values(column2)`

where

`$tablename = "table_".$column1;`

EDIT:

Also if it is not possible, now can i efficiently achieve the same with pdo and php.

Comment: Use merge query

Comment: @鄭有維 can you elaborate a bit more

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MySql documentaion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
[INTO] tbl_name
[PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
[(col_name,...)]
{VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
[ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  col_name=expr
    [, col_name=expr] ... ]
```

There is only on duplicate key update. There is no functionality for create table during insert.

If you really need this, you need to split it into 3 queries.
First:
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2='column2 value';

If by select query no result found then insert the reord.
else create table.

For implementing above you can use pdo prepare/query.

NOTE: It is not a good idea to create tables dynamically. If you do so, at the end of the day, you might have no idea, how many tables are there. You need to find some better algorithim.

Comment: I was making a table  for subject marks and as the number of subjects will be limited, i just want to create a new table when ever a new subject is added. Is dynamically creating not applicable for this too? If not, what do you suggest

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. Dynamically creating table is possible. But it is not a good idea. But as per your requirement, as the subject is limited, so there is not much issue for creating table dynamically.

For this , you need to split your logic into 3 queries. First: SELECT * FROM table WHERE column2='column2 value';
If by select query no result found then insert the reord. else create table.

Comment: By the way, as your subject is limited and you already know, then why you are ot creating tables manually (or) script, during installation ?

Comment: So that if more subjects are added later , an associated table will be created automatically. As the person who may add the new subject may not have any technical knowledge.

Comment: You can create a table named subject, where only subjects will be added. its fields will be subject_id [primary key], 'subject'.

In other table where you need the subject, keep subject_id as referance key,

Comment: But wouldn't roll-numbers become duplicated for each subject? and a roll-number can have around 20 subjects overall. So will that not be wasted data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143837/discussion-between-dinesh-patra-and-feetnappy).